# Try to open word, excel file from terminal emacs org-mode in WSL2?

Tags: excel, ms-word, hyperlink, emacs, wsl-2

I am working daily in terminal emacs-nox org-mode in WSL2. and I want to open word,
excel file by hyperlink.
I tried C-c C-o but as expected, it opens it in terminal mode.
I wonder if any way to do this.

Regards

onionsjk

I tried C-c C-o expecting word, excel file open in Window.
but it open in dummy terminal windows.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own question.

It was found in "The Org Manual Release 9.3".

In "4.5 Handling Links p.42", there is a statement:

```
 If you want to avoid opening in Emacs, use a C-u C-u prefix.
```

C-u C-u C-c C-o on "file:/mnt/d/temp/test.pptx",

at last, the file is open in powerpoint.